# GItLab CI/CD add variable only for develop branch

Tags: gitlab

I have a GitLab project that uses include and variables for the pipeline for example:

```
include:
 - project: a/b
   file: /file.gitlab-ci.yml

variables:
  Test: test
```

now I want that only for the develop branch a new boolean variable will be added/only when the pipeline runs from develop branch it will be true

```
    variables:
     Test: test
     Say hello: true
```

How can I add this to my gitlab-ci file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to use the `variables` keyword with the `rules` keyword to make this work. If you want it in your root configuration to have it impact every job, you'll use `workflow` keyword like this:

```
workflow:
  rules:
    - if: $CI_SOURCE_BRANCH == "develop"
      variables:
          TEST: true
          HELLO: true
```

If you want it to exist within just one job, use the same rules syntax but within just one job.